# Как записывать и считывать структуру в файл с расширением *.dat?

Tags: c, структуры

Мне необходимо создать файл, содержащий сведения о личной коллекции книголюба. Структура записи: шифр книги, автор, название, год издания, местоположение (номер стеллажа и т.п.).

Причем, запись (input()) и чтение (output()) структур производятся в файл/из файла с расширением *.dat .
При каждой новой записи у нас, по сути, добавляется новая структура.
Так вот, у меня не выходит никак нормально считывать. Выводит только последнюю записанную. 
Так же не получается вводить новый шифр книги для следующей структуры, он просто `gets(B.key);` пропускает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void input(void);
void output(void);

struct cd
{
    char key[12];
    char author[30];
    char title[20];
    int year;
    int location;
} B;

FILE *f;

void main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    system("cls");
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    while(n != 3)
    {
        puts("1. Ввод данных в базу");
        puts("2. Вывод всех авторов");
        puts("Для выхода из программы нажмите любую другую клавишу...");
        puts("\nВаш выбор: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1: input(); break;
            case 2: system("cls"); output(); break;
            default: exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void input(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int k = 0;
    if(( f = fopen("knigolub.dat","w")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Невозможно открыть файл");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (k != 10) {
        system("cls");
        puts("Введите сведения о книге...\n\n");
        printf("Введите шифр книги: ");
        gets(B.key);
        printf("Введите автора: ");
        gets(B.author);
        printf("Введите название: ");
        gets(B.title);
        printf("Введите год издания: ");
        scanf("%i", &B.year);
        printf("В какой стеллаж поместить? Введите его номер: ");
        scanf("%i", &B.location);
        fwrite(&B, sizeof(B), 1, f);
        puts("Продолжить работу?[y/n]");
        char s;
        scanf("%s", &s);
        switch ((int) s) {
            case (int) 'y': return input();
            case (int) 'n': return main();
        }
    }
}

void output (void)
{
    char letter;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    if((f=fopen("knigolub.dat","r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Невозможно открыть файл");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Шифр книги\tАвтор\tНазвание\tГод издания\tНомер стеллажа\n\n");
    while ((letter == fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\t\n", B.key, B.author, B.title, B.year, B.location);
    }
    getch();
    system("cls");
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: `while ((letter == fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\t\n", B.key, B.author, B.title, B.year, B.location);` - это, пардон, что такое?

Comment: @pink-tux посимвольное чтение из файла

Comment: Я догадался что не построчное. Но что этот бредовый код должен делать - вы сами себе хоть ответить можете? (почему нельзя читать `fgetc` в `char` - это уже настолько навязло в зубах, что даже упомниать лень...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Под *.dat обычно подразумевают некий бинарный псевдоформат. Потому  `fw = fopen("knigolub.dat","wb"))` и `fr = fopen("knigolub.dat","rb"))` и чтение-запись выполняем через fread и fwrite. Пусть в начале файла идет число записей (`size_t`):

```
size_t count = 0;
cd *buffer = NULL;

fread (&count, sizeof(size_t), 1, fr);

buffer = (cd*)malloc(sizeof(cd) * count);

fread (buffer, sizeof(cd), count, fr);
```

Записываем, соответственно, наоборот - сначала пишем число, затем структуры. Если нужно добавить структуру в файл - определяем смещение (`sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(cd)*count`), а затем записываем записываем в число в начале файла значение `count + 1`

Answer (score 5):

> Выводит только последнюю записанную.

Дело не в том, что ВЫВОДИТ последнюю записанную структуру, а в том, что при записи очередной структуры Вы  затираете (!!!) предыдущую. Каждый раз, когда выполняется вызов *input(...)*, Вы выполняете повторное открытие файла:

```
f = fopen("knigolub.dat","w")
```

При этом предыдущее содержимое файла ЗАТИРАЕТСЯ. Надо либо:

- Открывать один раз в начале работы всей программы
- Открывать с атрибутом добавления "a" (Open  for  appending:  writing  at end

of file)